# Android and gTalk

Tags: accounts, google-talk

I have three Gmail accounts. All of them are configured on my Samsung Galaxy 5. My phone is on Wi-Fi almost every time so accounts are always active. Gmail has an ability to chat. The problem is when I connect to one of my Gmail accounts using computer, I can  only see in gTalk that only one my Gmail account is active, online.

Always one and always the same... though all three accounts are online on my phone and ready to receive mails or talks. Others are always shown as offline. Maybe there is a program which helps to do this, or maybe the idea  is that this active account is the first on my phone?

Is it possible to do that all accounts would be shown as active in gTalk? Thank You all in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Talk app has now been replaced with [Hangouts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.talk). Unlike Talk, Hangouts allows switching from one account to another.

However, like most apps, you can't have two apps that are the same (i.e. a copy of an app) running at the same time. So, it wouldn't be possible to have multiple Hangouts accounts active simultaneously on the same phone.

Comment: Sounds like a contradiction to me: *Hangouts supports multiple accounts*, but *it wouldn't be possible to have multiple Hangouts (accounts) running on the same phone*? Or is it that while *Hangouts* does support multiple accounts, and one can switch between them, still only one of the accounts can be active at a given time?

Comment: @Izzy Perhaps, multiple users is the correct term? In Talk before, you could only use it with 1 user, even though you had other accounts on the phone. You could not change this user.

Comment: No, accounts is fine. But if I guessed right, it might be more clear to write "active simultaneously on the same device" instead of "running on the same phone". But I'm no native English speaker either :)

Comment: @Izzy I reworded my answer so that it's more or less appropriate. But hopefully, it makes sense.